# Angular 4 download xls

Tags: php, excel, angular

i'm trying to download excel file (.xls) using angular and php for backend

my backend already send my excel file as response, and when i check it, it return with correct format

but my angular 4 is returning the file as corrupted format (it contain some symbols like `ï¿½ï¿½à¡±ï¿½;ï¿½ï¿½` )

below is my angular code:

Service

```
private headers = new Headers({
 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
});

downloadTemplate() {
  this.options = new RequestOptions();
  this.options.headers = this.headers;

  const params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
  params.set('token', this.currentUser.token);
  this.options.search = params;

  return this.http.get(environment.api_host + '/template', this.options);
}
```

Component

```
template() {
  this._apiService.downloadTemplate().subscribe((response) => {
    const blob = new Blob([(<any>response)._body], {type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel'});
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download = 'template.xls';
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
  });
}
```

from my code, is there something that i miss?

Comment: http://brianflove.com/2017/11/02/angular-http-client-blob/

Answer (score 0):

If subscription is not necessary then just use this in `downloadTemplate()` method in your service

```
  window.location.href = your_URL;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using FileSaver library for serving files from Angular apps: http://alferov.github.io/angular-file-saver/

Here you have sample code:

```
getTemplate(): Observable<Blob> {
    this.apiService.http()
        .get(environment.api_host + '/template', { responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob })
        .map(r => r.blob())
        .subscribe(
            template => {
                FileSaver.saveAs(new Blob([template]), "template.xml");
            },
            error => {
                console.error(error);
            }
        );
}
```

Important is that you should add header `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` to your PHP response. Complete and working set of headers:

```
$file = fopen("/tmp/examplefile.xls", "r");

array(
    'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="' . basename($filePath) . '"',
    'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream',
    'Content-Length' => filesize($filePath),
    'Expires' => '@0',
    'Cache-Control' => 'must-revalidate',
    'Pragma' => 'public'
);
```

I think the problem in your code is header definition: `const blob = new Blob([(<any>response)._body], {type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel'});` or response type in http client options. You should send 'octet/stream' from PHP(binary data). In angular create Blob object from this data and return Blob object to user. That's all.